# iOS, What does this notation ({ ...something in it... }) mean for?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm a new iOS developer.

Today, I faced a ***({})*** notation.

### Question

What does this mean?
And why do I need this ?
 Can I just not using it?

See the code below:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *myTableView;

 _myTableView = ({
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    tableView;
});
```

According to what I have learned , the block is something like

```
int (^myBock)(int) = ^(int num) { return num* value;}
```

So what does the ({}) here mean ? It can not match the pattern above I think.

Comment: What part of "2 questions is 2 questions" do you not understand?

Comment: @AshishKakkad if I use it like this , What will happen?

Comment: @musefan I don't understand Why I can pass a thing like ({}) with something wrapped in it to a UITableView variable

Comment: Not what I mean. I mean, if you have 2 questions then you should post them as 2 separate questions on Stack Overflow. Do not create 1 question to group all your questions together

Comment: So sorry. I will separate them next time , but Question2 here already been answered. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Q1.
When some method/function accepts block and you want to pass an empty block you use ({}) , of course nil will also work , but not always , if function/method that takes block argument does not check that its not a nil before executing it , application will crash , some methods ( like uiviewanimation ) are checking that you did provide a block and not nil and only then execute block , but as I said not all functions/methods ( 3rd party ) check that.

Q2.
if you use self directly in a block , this block will retain "self" object, it means that even if "self" is no longer used an needs to be deallocated ( for example it is an UIViewController and you dismissed/closed it ), it is still being retained with block and it wont allow it to release/dealloc until that block is executed or released itself

You can learn more at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aS6PBmBAP1g

Comment: really thank you for the question2 , but for the question 1 , why can I pass a Block to a UITableView?

Comment: because it is "wrapped" like object , like "id"

Comment: So it's the tableView in ({}) that passed to the UITableView ? I really curious Why we need this code style. Can we just _myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];    Will there be any different?

Comment: I dont understand your question , this is just a code block , its not returning the tableView ,

please have  a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aS6PBmBAP1g

Comment: I already watch the youtube video , but if here the ({ ... }) pass to the _maTableView is a block , where is the ^ notation? Can I define a block without the " ^ " ?